# the value of y is assigned how

Tags: javascript

I am looking at this function

```
function foo(x) {
  var tmp = 3;
  return function (y) {
    alert(x + y + (++tmp));
  }
}
var bar = foo(2); // bar is now a closure.
bar(10);
```

when I run it, the variables get the following values

x = 2,
y = 10
tmp = 3.

Now I see that in foo(2) x is passed as 2. So its understandable that x is getting the value of 2. But then bar(10) is assigning a value of 0 to y. Hows that? I am confused on how does the receiving function know that 10 is the value for y assigned by bar(10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo(2)` returns an anonymous function which accepts one parameter (`y`). As you're setting `bar` to be the return value of `foo(2)`, `bar` becomes a reference to that anonymous function.

So, when you call `bar(10)` you're calling the anonymous function `foo` returns, and so `10` is being set to the parameter `y`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *closure*.

When you write:

```
var bar = foo(2);
```

it's actually *calling* `foo`, so the net result is:

```
var bar = function (y) {
    alert(2 + y + (++tmp));
}
```

where `tmp` is the value bound in scope by the closure.

So, subsequently calling:

```
bar(10);
```

is passing `10` into *that* function, with the result being:

```
alert(2 + 10 + (++tmp));
```

`tmp` will increase each time you call *any* function created with `foo`